# Installing ubuntu error end of file while reading /dev/sda

Tags: hard-drive, dell

I am using Dell Inspiron laptop. I run Dell diagnostic and got error 2000-0142 .
When I tried to install Ubuntu on that machine Ive got error:
"end of file while reading /dev/sda"

Any idea what causes it and how can I fix it?
Might be I need to replace my hard drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a hard drive failure, but maybe just a loose cable.
See https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Hard-Drive-Failed-during-diagnostic-Error-Code-2000-0142/td-p/4010351

---

Google Dell Inspiron error 2000-0151 and get [HDD, 3E Smart Predictive Failure](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Error-Code-2000-0151-HDD-3E-Smart-Predictive-Failure/td-p/4650333)

Time to backup what you can, your drive is failing.  See the smartctl -a /dev/sda  output for details.

Comment: That's right , maybe the cable , you can make sure by connecting the hard to another working device or changing the cable.

Comment: I've checked the cable. I run diagnose again and now I'm getting error 2000-0151. the hard drive being recognize at system information